# How do I plot a variable number of sets in a python bar chart using matplotlib?

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to write a code that, based on an input dataset, can print a grouped bar chart corresponding to the data set. The dataset can have different scenarios, and each scenario can have different methods. I want to print a group of bars (representing the different methods) for each scenario (see picture below for an example).

[image: Example bar chart]

The problem is that neither the number of methods nor the number of scenarios are fixed. I cannot figure out how to make my code adapt to different situations. so far my code reads the data set and creates a dictionary where the keys are the different methods, and the values are dictionaries of the scenarios as key and the final value as values.

Example

```
my_dict = {method1: {scenario1: value1, scenario2: value2, ...}, method2: {scenario1: value1, scenario2: value2, ...}}
```

I just cannot figure out how to use this dictionary to plot my data. I know that usually I would need to define my categories lists(methods in the example above) but since the number of lists (methods) is variable, I am stuck and don't know how to move from here. Any help will be highly appreciated!

I couldn't figure out how to use my nested dictionary to define the different sets to plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import seaborn as sns

my_dict = pd.DataFrame({'method1': {'scenario1': 10, 'scenario2': 20, 'scenario3': 1}, 'method2': {'scenario1': 15, 'scenario2': 5, 'scenario3': 1.5}})

my_dict = my_dict.reset_index()

df = my_dict.melt(id_vars='index')

g = sns.catplot(data=df, x="index", y="value", hue="variable", kind="bar")
```

This gives me the follow plot:

[image]